# Screen scraping an application window and interacting with the mouse and keyboard

Tags: c#, graphics, screen-scraping, graphical-interaction

The other day I found myself addicted to a Flash game and frustrated by the thing at the same time.  In a moment of frustration with the game I thought I would make a 'bot' to beat it for me.  Well, I really wouldn't, but it made me realize: I don't know how to interact with another application in a way to do this.  Which brings me to the question, **how would one take screenshots of another running application and interact with it with the keyboard and mouse**.  Ideally the solution would be in a managed language like c#.

When doing the background reading the net was drowning with articles on scraping HTML. There were not many articles on actually screen scraping an application.

I'm looking for a way to interface with another application rather than script/macro another application.

Could something like Xming be used to redirect the interface?  http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/

Perhaps a Terminal Services client?
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RemoteDesktop_CSharpNET.aspx

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you are looking for a "visual programming" approach, go for Sikuli. If you are looking for a programmable/selective screen recorder ("screen scraper"), maybe VNC is easiest to use. The server is already there, and the client is pretty simple to write (i wrote a simple Java client in ~300 lines of code, GUI and all).

Comment: I was looking for a way to capture screenshots of an application and manipulate the keyboard/mouse from something like c# (as opposed to a static script).  The thought was a program would do some image work from the screenshot, and then respond with keyboard/mouse input.  Sikuli looks great, however, it's a little different from what I am looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out Sikuli, it is basically what you are looking for. It is written in Java however.

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/

Comment: Another +1 for Sikuli only wished they had a .NET api to programatically access that powerful engine.  Maybe someday.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making the bot which did all this and documented it in a post

http://www.charlesrcook.com/archive/2010/09/05/creating-a-bejeweled-blitz-bot-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have used [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for application automation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i'm looking to interact with the application more than automate